# What is the latest version of jdk for Windows XP 32bit SP3?

Tags: java-6

I want to update JDK for NetBeans 7.1 and tried JDK 8u65 for windows i586 but a message box appears warning me about the old OS not being supported anymore.

The PC is not mine, is from the job and they don't want to update the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml

Java 7 is the latest version that can run on XP, but it is not supported by Sun

> Note: As of April 8, 2014 Microsoft stopped supporting Windows XP and therefore it is no longer an officially supported platform. Users may still continue to use Java 7 updates on Windows XP at their own risk